# Can I buy a Ubuntu OS DVD?

Tags: software-installation

I need an OS that I can install on older XP computers. I do not understand computer slang, brain is too aged. I do print instructions that use words identical to what is found in the OS.

So I need to BUY a plug & play option with simple settings. I am limited to dialup, long downloads fail because of telemarketer intrusions.

The OS needs to be proven & current & available in Ontario Canada.
Can someone help this senior get out of the failing XP?